# How to count separate items in list from input

Tags: python

Making a simple program which responds to the user's inputs.

In the example, the input "I like math", would return the response "That's cool".
I want the response to change if the user inputs two items from the list, for example "I like math and biology".

I decided to get this done by using the count function, but it always returns the value 0.
What would I have to do to get the *if* response?

```
list = ["math", "physics", "biology", "computer science"]
favsub = input("What are your favorite subjects? \n")
favsub = favsub.lower()
favsub = favsub.split()
num = favsub.count(list)
if num == 2:
    print("Both?")
else
    print("That's cool")
```

The code above is a simplified example, if you want to see the actual code, I'll leave it in a google doc [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1uxkvX5GbSM0dROnbUJ9HEUcBVDkwhFNaizqd3LpPEWs/edit?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`list.count(x)`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/list/count.html) only counts a single element `x`. Of course, your list is not an element of `favsub` and it does not magically sum the counts of its elements. However, building on your approach, you can do the following, using [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum):

```
favsub = input("...").lower()
# do not split, otherwise you can't count "computer science" 
num = sum(x in favsub for x in list)
```

Generally, you should not name variables `list` (or `str`, `int`, etc.) as it shadows built-in names.

Answer (score 2):

You could make list and favsub sets instead, and the take the length of the intersection.

NOTE: This will only work if all the phrases in list and favsub are single words, without a space.

Comment: the problem is `computer science` is not one word.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is too naive. First you will have to tokenize the user input (what if the user inputs `math,physics` instead of `math and physics`? `.split` will not separate `math` from `physics` in this case).

Then you will need to call `favsub.count` with each memeber of `list` (which is a bad variable name by the way as it shadows the built-in `list`).

I will suggest another naive (but easier) approach. Forget about splitting and tokenizing the user input. Simply search each recognized subject and sum the results:

```
 subjects_list = ["math", "physics", "biology", "computer science"]
 favsub = input("What are your favorite subjects? \n")
 favsub = favsub.lower()
 count = 0
 for subject in subjects_list:
     if subject in favsub:
         count += 1
 print(count)
```

This is essentially the same as @schwobaseggl's answer but with an explicit counter.